# What is the requestString parameter when calling the graphql method in graphql.js?

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I'm working through `graphql.org`'s "Getting Started With GraphQL.js." In the tutorial, the `graphql` method gets called like so:

```
graphql(schema, '{ hello }', root).then((response) => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

My confusion is with the second parameter - `'{ hello }'`. I really don't know what I'm even looking at. Is this using the Javascript Object Property Value Shorthand, so it really means `'{ hello: hello }'`? If so, does the `hello` value in that object refer to 'hello' resolver function? And if *that's* the case, then what is the key in this object used for?

Or does this have some meaning in the GraphQL syntax that I'm not aware of?

I am quite turned around.

Comment: I think GraphQL has their own syntax, check the query-example here: [https://graphql.org/learn/](https://graphql.org/learn/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [official tutorial](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/) for GraphQL.js shows schemas that are built using Schema Definition Language (SDL). While SDL is specific to GraphQL, it is **not** actually GraphQL. The actual "query language" part of GraphQL has a separate, well-documented syntax -- it's this syntax that's used to write the requests that are sent from a client to a GraphQL server. SDL, on the other hand, is used to create a schema, which defines the capabilities of a particular GraphQL service.

The two syntaxes do have some similarities (for example, they both use curly brackets), but are not interchangeable.

If we define a GraphQL schema using SDL like this:

```
type Query {
  hello: String
  goodbye: String
}
```

We are saying that our query root operation type has two fields that clients can request -- `hello` and `goodbye`. As a client, we can request one or both fields using GraphQL syntax:

```
query {
  hello
}
```

or...

```
query {
  hello
  goodbye
}
```

Any extra white space between tokens is ignored, so the second query is equivalent to:

```
query { hello goodbye }
```

Additionally, if we're using a `query` operation, as opposed to `mutation` or `subscription`, we can drop the `query` keyword altogether and GraphQL will assume it's a query. This is know as *query shorthand*:

```
{
  hello
  goodbye
}
```

The [official tutorial](https://graphql.org/learn) does a pretty good job of explaining how to craft GraphQL requests. You can also take a look at [the specification](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/) for a full explanation and complete examples.